# How to scale for SelectKBest for feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I am trying [SelectKBest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) to select out most important features:

```
# SelectKBest: 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
sel = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')

# Load Dataset: 
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris() 

# Run SelectKBest on scaled_iris.data
newx = sel.fit_transform(iris.data, iris.target)
print(newx[0:5])
```

It works all right and the output is:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]
```

However, when I try to use `SelectKBest` on scaled data, I get error:

```
# Scale iris.data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler    
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(iris.data) 

# Run SelectKBest on scaled_iris.data
newx = sel.fit_transform(X, iris.target)
```

Output is error:

```
ValueError: Input X must be non-negative.
```

How can I scale the data so that there are no negative values for this purpose? Or is scaling completely unnecessary while selecting features from a dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the chi2 scoring function. If you instead use the f_classif scoring function, then there will not be any errors due to having negative values in your dataset. So if you want to use chi2, then you would need to transform your data somehow to get rid of negatives (you could normalize it so that all the values fall between 0 and 1, or you could set your minimum value to 0, or do countless things to remove the negatives). If you're already using some sort of normalized values such as z-scores and therefore don't want to do any more normalization, then you should consider using the ANOVA (f_classif) scoring function for your feature selection.

So essentially, to answer the question directly, additional scaling to get rid of negatives may not be necessary for selecting features from a dataset. If you are using z-score normalization or some other normalization that uses negatives (maybe your data falls between -1 and +1), you could just use f_classif scoring function which doesn't require only positive numbers.

As one example of how you can make the data scale to use chi2: When I've used the chi2 scoring function in sklearn, I start with data that are not normalized at all. I then normalize the data so that it falls between 0 and 1 very simply by doing this:

`normed_data= (data - data.min(0)) / data.ptp(0)`

Here, `data.min(0)` returns the minimum value of each data column and `data.ptp(0)` returns the range of each data column. So `normed_data` ends up being a matrix where every column has been independently normalized to fall within the range of [0, 1].

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. It may be even better if you expand on how to `"do countless things to remove the negatives"`, since the question is mainly for that.

Comment: @rnso I added what I specifically did to remove the negatives when I came up against this. It's not the only way to do it, but it's the only way I've tried myself. I also clarified that my answer falls more along the line of "scaling isn't necessary for feature selection" (a question you asked) because the reason for this issue is not due to the feature selection itself, but instead due to the chi2 scoring function chosen for the feature selection.

Comment: But generally, is it a good idea to do any scaling prior to select k best or should that come afterwards? Independently of whether you want to use chi2 and have negative data.

Comment: @Odisseo I am not speaking as an expert here and in truth I don't really know. But it seems to me that scaling should happen before feature selection. Scaling can affect classifiers immensely. Therefore, it seems counter-productive to me to apply feature selection on a dataset that will then be changed for the classifier. With that said, if the concern is one of experimental rigor and "experimenter degrees of freedom", absolutely all of this should be done in a principled manner without slicing the data hundreds of ways just to report the one arbitrary way that everything works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html). By default, it will scale the data within the range $[0,1]$:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
scaler.transform(X)
```